# Definition of single k-slice

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

This is from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold (2nd Ed.) page 101. What do we mean
with a *single k-slice*? Maybe a connected one?

[image: Slice Charts]

Comment: It's a normal slice it just means the intersection is that one slice and has no overlap with other slices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning here is completely literal: "single $k$-slice" means "one $k$-slice".  If you like, the word "single" can be omitted, so the statement is just that $S\cap U$ is a $k$-slice of $U$.  The word "single" is emphasizing that $S\cap U$ is equal to just one $k$-slice of $U$ rather being a union of multiple different $k$-slices.